# How does quantum state teleportation works?

Tags: quantum-gate, qiskit, entanglement

I've started learning Quantum Computing from the Qiskit Textbook and was able to easily understand or work out everything until it came to the working of [Quantum Teleportation](https://qiskit.org/textbook/ch-algorithms/teleportation.html)

I can understand the procedure of it, but cannot understand why it works and was unable to work out the math of it. I also couldn't find any source that explained this is in a more simplistic manner.

Here's the procedure that I have copy-pasted from the textbook:

> Step 1: Alice and Bob create an entangled pair of qubits and each one
>   of them holds on to one of the two qubits in the pair.
>
> The pair they create is a special pair called a Bell pair. In quantum
>   circuit language, the way to create a Bell pair between two qubits is
>   to first transfer one of them to the Bell basis ( |+⟩  and  |−⟩ ) by
>   using a Hadamard gate, and then to apply a CNOT gate onto the other
>   qubit controlled by the one in the Bell basis.
>
> Let's say Alice owns  q1  and Bob owns  q2  after they part ways.
>
> Step 2: Alice applies a CNOT gate on  q1 , controlled by  |ψ⟩  (the
>   qubit she is trying to send Bob).
>
> Step 3: Next, Alice applies a Hadamard gate to  |ψ⟩ , and applies a
>   measurement to both qubits that she owns -  q1  and  |ψ⟩ .
>
> Step 4: Then, it's time for a phone call to Bob. She tells Bob the
>   outcome of her two qubit measurement. Depending on what she says, Bob
>   applies some gates to his qubit,  q2 . The gates to be applied, based
>   on what Alice says, are as follows :
>
> 00  →  Do nothing
>
> 01  →  Apply  X  gate
>
> 10  →  Apply  Z  gate
>
> 11  →  Apply  ZX  gate
>
> Note that this transfer of information is classical.
>
> And voila! At the end of this protocol, Alice's qubit has now
>   teleported to Bob.

Comment: What part of the algorithm you don't understand? Note, in Step 4, you perform an operation based on the measurement outcome.

Comment: Apologies for not making it clear enough. I don't understand why we're different gates depending upon the measurement. I understand that is the way to make teleportation work but I cannot see how it's happening.

Comment: @Martin Vesely it indeed helps in understanding the maths behind it, yet I'm not sure if I grasp the intuitiveness behind it, an excellent answer on the question btw.

Comment: @IEIrodov: Thanks. I am afraid that it is very hard to explain anything in quantum mechanics (and computing) intuitively (with exception to the most simple things). I would recommed to go step by step in circuit implementing the quantum transportation and see how quantum state of entangled qubits change. Maybe it helps.

Comment: this question is too broad as it stands. You should focus on a specific thing you do not understand about the derivation and ask about that